# I can't watch some Videos in fullscreen with Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, flash, video-streaming

When I try to watch Videos in Fullscreen with my Webbrowser, it doesn't matter wether Firefox or Chrome, only at some video sites the whole panel disappears, sometimes the panel does not disappear, and sometimes half of the Activities Button stays there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I updated to Gnome 3 this week.  Get the latest version of flash here (11.2.202.291): http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect . You want the tar.gz version, not the YUM or RPM.  The fill will be called **install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz**  if you're running 64 bit for example.

Next In chrome go check out your flash version using this URL

chrome://flash/

You should see:

**Chromium  25.0.1364.160 (Ubuntu 13.04)  <--OLD**

OS  Linux

Flash plugin    11.2 **r202** /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so  <--location

Next extract and install the new version of flash you just downloaded

```
mkdir flash
mv install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz flash/
cd flash/
tar zxvf install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz 
more readme.txt 
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

Reload chrome and enjoy full screen.